# VS Code: Hotkey to move cursor to current find and replace selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, once I've found some matching text via find-and-replace (Ctrl+F), is there a hotkey to move  the cursor to the currently matched selection in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling, I've found that `Esc` works, but I'll leave the question up in case anyone knows of anything more ergonomic.